# Name for boundedness property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, terminology

Let $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an interval and let $f$: $I\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function with the property that $f$ is bounded on every $[a, b]$, where $[a, b]\subseteq U\subseteq I$ with $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}$ (not just in $I$) wrt. the standard topology.

Does this property have a name? Note that it is not the same as local boundedness since $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $f(0)=0$ has the above property on $[0, 1]$, but is not locally bounded around $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing else than local boundedness in the *interior* of $I$. Note that for arbitrary $a$, $b$ there exists an open subset $U$ with $[a, b] \subset U \subset I$ if and only if $[a, b] \subset I^\circ$.